# In ObjectBox, what's an easy way to search for a full word under a String property?

Tags: objectbox

I have a property named "sentence" which is a String.  Say I want to find all sentences containing "in" as a word (not any string piece).  What's an easy way?  "contains" doesn't seem to accept regex like "\bin\b"?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use a two level approach:

1. Use "contains" query criteria to reduce the number of candidates without regex
2. Apply a [query filter](https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#query-filters) with the regex to get the actual results

In code it should look something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(myRegexPattern);
// Reduce object count to reasonable value.
box.query().contains(MyType_.myText, "in")
        // Filter is performed on candidate objects.
        .filter((obj) -> pattern.matcher(obj.myText).matches());
```

Step 1 is mostly to reduce the result set from all objects to candidate objects. This is done more efficiently on the database side.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of API, a simple way to do this is to use String.matches(), passing in a regex to match against the entire string:

```
if (str.matches(".*?\\bin\\b.*")) {
    ....
}
```

Otherwise, you can use the Pattern and Matcher classes to do "full" regex matching. Essentially, compiler a Pattern object, create a Matcher from it into your string, and this then gives you a find() method in addition to matches(). For example:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bin\\b");
    if (p.matcher(str).find()) {

    }
```

The latter is more flexible because you can do things such as set matcher options (e.g. case sensitivity) more easily or query the actual positions of the matches.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry my question wasn't clear enough.  It's regarding queries from ObjectBox db.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = """
The dishes go in the dishwasher. 
Please put the plates in the sink.
The dishes are in your room
hahahaha
in room
..... in
inin
you wont find the word you are looking for"""

pattern = re.compile(".*\\bin\\b.*",flags=re.M)

print(pattern.findall(s))

# ("\w.*\\bin\\b.*",flags=re.M)
```

**1)** .* = select any word, character , digit etc.

**2)** \b = word boundary which means that you are locking the word initial from the beginning so for example sentence = 'this inis the' here,only using the \bin will also match the sentence 'this inis the' since you are only marking the boundary from the beginning and not the end. \b[word]\b will do the job in your case

**3)** flags = re.M allows us to consider each line separately. otherwise the match would be on the entire string 's' instead of each line

**4)** findall finds the match

Comment: Thank you, but sorry my question wasn't clear enough. It's regarding queries from ObjectBox db.